# ANTLR prioritizing optional tag over non-optional tag

Tags: antlr4

Hard to explain with the title, but here's the problem:
I'm trying to parse an equation with ANTLR4.

My current definition of a number:

```
NUMBER: SUBTRACTION? DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)? ;
```

Where DIGIT and SUBTRACTION are all digits and '-' respectively.
My parser rule for subtraction:

```
subtraction: value? SUBTRACTION (value|operation)?;
```

The idea is the parser still works with a missing value.
Let's say I have this input

```
1-2
```

The problem is with this input, ANTLR says that 1 is a number, and -2 is a number. ANTLR doesn't group it as subtraction, like 1 SUBTRACTION 2.

What can I do to get the correct grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define rules like this:

```
SUBTRACTION : '-';
NUMBER      : SUBTRACTION? DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)? ;
```

input like `-2` will always be a single `NUMBER` token: it will never be tokenised as separate `SUBTRACTION` and `NUMBER` tokens. ANTLR always tries to match as much characters as possible.

You should not glue the `-` to the `NUMBER` in the lexer, but do that in the parser like `SUBTRACTION expr`:

```
expr
 : SUBTRACTION expr
 | expr SUBTRACTION expr
 | NUMBER
 ;

SUBTRACTION : '-';
NUMBER      : DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)? ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

which will parse both `1-2` and `-2` correctly.

Comment: Great idea! I have a "value" parser rule which takes in numbers, so I put SUBTRACTION there, and it works like a charm.